# Why does R truncate decimal places from long numbers and how do I prevent it?

Tags: r

When I input a "short" number with decimal places in R, the decimal places are represented:

```
> c(5.4, 3.8)
[1] 5.4 3.8
```

But when I input a "long" number with decimal places, the decimal places are rounded in R:

```
> 1.00000004
[1] 1

> 3434456.9 - 0.1
[1] 3434457
```

Why is that and how do I keep my decimal places? I do not want a rounded result!

Comment: Decimal places are not lost, they are just not printed. We can control how many digits to print, see linked post.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you, that answers my question.